# Name a variable with an exclamation in Julia

Tags: julia, naming-conventions, naming, variable-names

I got confused about using an exclamation to name a variable in this [link](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/).

Firstly, it works fine in the `JuliaPro Command Prompt`

[image]

Then, I closed the `JuliaPro Command Prompt` and opened it again, trying to test different variable namings:

[image]

I could not understand how to use an exclamation.

Comment: Always put spaces between operators and variables or literals. It is good practice, and makes your code prettier and easier to read. And you avoid parsing pitfalls such as this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a space after `!`. Without a space Julia treats `!=` as inequality test.

You can check how Julia parses an expression by using `parse` function and sending the required expression in a string (and then using `dump` to see the parsed structure), e.g.:

```
julia> parse("x! =1")
:(x! = 1)

julia> dump(parse("x! =1"))
Expr
  head: Symbol =
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Symbol x!
    2: Int64 1
  typ: Any

julia> parse("x!=1")
:(x != 1)

julia> dump(parse("x!=1"))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol !=
    2: Symbol x
    3: Int64 1
  typ: Any
```

And you can see that the first expression is an assignment and the second is a call to `!=` function.